# Cannot pass a CSV value (java preparedStatement) to a SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: java, sql-server, csv

I'm getting this error "ERROR CONVERTING DATA TYPE NVARCHAR TO INT" when I try to execute a prepared Statement, passing a String CSV(@selectedResources) to a VARCHAR parameter in a SQL Server Stored Procedure:

Java code:

```
 public void setFields(IEntity argEntity, StormPS pstmt) throws SQLException          {
   IMeal t_Meal = (IMeal) argEntity;
   pstmt.setInt(1, t_Meal.getTourId());
   pstmt

   .setTimestamp(2, StormContext

     .dateToTimestamp(t_Meal.getDateTimeStartActual()));
 pstmt.setTimestamp(3, StormContext.dateToTimestamp(t_Meal.getDateTimeEndActual()));
pstmt.setInt(4, t_Meal.getJobElementId());
pstmt.setBoolean(5, t_Meal.getOTE());
pstmt.setBoolean(6, t_Meal.getBillable());
pstmt.setBoolean(7, t_Meal.getAutoAdd());
pstmt.setInt(8, t_Meal.getUpdatingUserId());
pstmt.setString(9, t_Meal.getIpAddress());
pstmt.setString(10, t_Meal.getSelectedResources());
}
```

Stored Procedure's parameters:

```
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MealUpdate]
   @@TourId   INT,  
   @@DateTimeStartActual  DATETIME,  
   @@DateTimeEndActual  DATETIME,  
   @@JobElementId  INT,  
   @@OTE   BIT,  
   @@Billable  BIT,  
   @@AutoAdd  BIT,  
   @@UpdatingUserId INT,  
   @@IPAddress  VARCHAR(20),  
   @@SelectedResources VARCHAR(300)
```

At first I realiced that my preparedStatement had defined the parameters like this [9105267, 2016-05-18 04:30:00.0, 2016-05-18 05:30:00.0, 0, false, false, false, 23939, 127.0.0.1, **8224483,8149293,8149281,8149272**] (values '8224483,8149293,8149281,8149272' are the @selectedResources String parameter). Then I decided to add single quotes to the String like this [9105267, 2016-05-18 04:30:00.0, 2016-05-18 05:30:00.0, 0, false, false, false, 23939, 127.0.0.1, **'8224483,8149293,8149281,8149272'**] , but the same error keeps showing.

I hope being enough clear with my question.

Complete Stored Procedure:

```
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MealUpdate]
  @@TourId   INT,  
  @@DateTimeStartActual  DATETIME,  
  @@DateTimeEndActual  DATETIME,  
  @@JobElementId  INT,  
  @@OTE   BIT,  
  @@Billable  BIT,  
  @@AutoAdd  BIT,  
  @@UpdatingUserId INT,  
  @@IPAddress  VARCHAR(20),  
  @@SelectedResources VARCHAR(300),  
  @@Id    INT,  
  @@UpdatingDateTime DATETIME = NULL    
AS 
SET NOCOUNT ON 
SET XACT_ABORT ON

BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

        DECLARE @ErrCode INT  
        DECLARE @contractRuleId int
        DECLARE @OldMealLenght int
        DECLARE @OldDateTimeStartActual DATETIME
        DECLARE @NewMealLenght int

         IF  @@UpdatingDateTime IS NULL  
          SET @@UpdatingDateTime = GETDATE()  

        BEGIN TRY  
         EXEC MealValidate @@TourId,  
              @@DateTimeStartActual,  
              @@DateTimeEndActual,  
              @@JobElementId  OUTPUT,  
              @@Id  

        END TRY  
        BEGIN CATCH  
         DECLARE @message as varchar(200)  
         DECLARE @severity as int  
         DECLARE @state as int  
         DECLARE @number as int  
         set @message = ERROR_MESSAGE()  
         set @severity = ERROR_SEVERITY()  
         set @state = ERROR_STATE()  
         set @number = ERROR_NUMBER()  
         if @number = 50000  
          RAISERROR(@message,@severity,@state)  
         else  
          RAISERROR('Error in Meals. Unknown code. Please contact STORM administrator',16,1)  
         RETURN  
        END CATCH  

        select @contractRuleId = ContractRuleId from tours WITH(NOLOCK) where id = @@TourId and isdisabled = 0

        select  @OldDateTimeStartActual = M.DateTimeStartActual,
                @OldMealLenght = datediff(minute,M.DateTimeStartActual,M.DateTimeEndActual)
        from MEALS M with(nolock)
        where M.id = @@Id

        set @NewMealLenght = datediff(minute,@@DateTimeStartActual,@@DateTimeEndActual)

        if(@OldDateTimeStartActual <> @@DateTimeStartActual or @OldMealLenght <> @NewMealLenght)
        begin
            EXEC TourIndicatorsDeleteFromMealEvent @contractRuleId,@@TourId,@@UpdatingUserId
            EXEC TourIndicatorsCreateFromPayTransaction @contractRuleId,@@TourId,@@UpdatingUserId
        end

         UPDATE MEALS  
         SET [TourId]  =@@TourId,  
          [DateTimeStartActual] =@@DateTimeStartActual,  
          [DateTimeEndActual] =@@DateTimeEndActual,  
          JobElementId  =@@JobElementId,  
          OTE   =@@OTE,  
          Billable  =@@Billable,  
          AutoAdd   =0,  
          UpdatingDateTime =@@UpdatingDateTime,  
          UpdatingUserId  =@@UpdatingUserId,  
          IPAddress  =@@IPAddress,  
          DoLog   =1  
         WHERE [Id]   =@@Id  

             **INSERT INTO dbo.table_fab SELECT * FROM [dbo].[CSVToTable](@@SelectedResources)**

         /* Tests how many rows effected, and returns an error if no rows were found  
          for update.  
         */  

         IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0  
         BEGIN  
          RAISERROR(' There was no meal to update.',15,1)  
          ----WITH LOG  
         END    

        EXEC TourIndicatorsCreateFromMealEvent @contractRuleId,@@TourId,@@UpdatingUserId

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    -- Test XACT_STATE:
        -- If 1, the transaction is committable.
        -- If -1, the transaction is uncommittable and should 
        --     be rolled back.
        -- XACT_STATE = 0 means that there is no transaction and
        --     a commit or rollback operation would generate an error.

    -- Test whether the transaction is uncommittable.
    IF (XACT_STATE()) = -1
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END

    -- Test whether the transaction is committable.
    IF (XACT_STATE()) = 1
    BEGIN
        COMMIT TRANSACTION   
    END

    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000)
    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT
    DECLARE @ErrorState INT
    DECLARE @ErrorNumber INT

    SELECT 
        @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
        @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
        @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE(),
        @ErrorNumber = ERROR_NUMBER()

    -- Only log non-user defined errors
    IF (@ErrorNumber <> 50000)
    BEGIN 
        -- Execute error retrieval routine.
        EXECUTE [dba_admin].[dbo].[s_LogSQLError]
    END

    -- Use RAISERROR inside the CATCH block to return error
    -- information about the original error that caused
    -- execution to jump to the CATCH block.
    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, -- Message text.
               @ErrorSeverity, -- Severity.
               @ErrorState -- State.
                )
END CATCH
```

CSVToTable function:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CSVToTable] (@InStr VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS @TempTab TABLE
   (id int not null)
AS
BEGIN
    ;-- Ensure input ends with comma
    SET @InStr = REPLACE(@InStr + ',', ',,', ',')
    DECLARE @SP INT
DECLARE @VALUE VARCHAR(1000)
WHILE PATINDEX('%,%', @INSTR ) <> 0 
BEGIN
   SELECT  @SP = PATINDEX('%,%',@INSTR)
   SELECT  @VALUE = LEFT(@INSTR , @SP - 1)
   SELECT  @INSTR = STUFF(@INSTR, 1, @SP, '')
   INSERT INTO @TempTab(id) VALUES (@VALUE)
END
    RETURN
END
GO
```

UPDATE (Solution):

Within the Java class that executes the preparedStatement, there is a constant which defines the number of fields that will be send as parameters, this constant was defined in 9:

**private final static int FIELDS_NUMBER = 9;**

As I was adding a new parameter (selectedResources), I needed to redefine this constant to 10. I was sending @selectedResouces to the position of @Id(which has int as type). This is basically the reason I was getting this error. Kind of beginner mistake.

Comment: The problem is in the stored procedure code, and not the way you are passing the parameters.   Please post the entire stored procedure code.   I'll bet a donut that you are using the SelectedResources parameter in an `IN` clause, which doesn't work and is a very common beginner mistake.

Comment: I added the complete stored procedure

Comment: You have a number of issues here. Let's start with all your variable names...why are they all using @@??? Then you have littered your procedure with NOLOCK hints. Are you ok with inaccurate results? That hint can and will return missing and/or duplicate rows. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/ For the actual issue at hand...you appear to be using a table valued function named CSVToTable. Without the definition of that function we can't offer much help.

Comment: Yes, we would need to see the code of that function, and the DDL of `dbo.table_fab `

Comment: I have added the definition of CSVToTable function

Comment: Wait, are you actually passing the word "false" to bit-type parameters???  Your CSVToTable function works fine, what is not clear from your code is exactly what values end up getting passed to the parameters.   I recommend that you use profiler to see exactly what command is being sent from your application to your SQL Server, and if the problem isn't obvious from that, please post it.